# How to compare two different structured excel in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Let say i have file1.xlsx and file2.xlsx with columns ['id','name','role','gender'] and ['id','country','role'] respectively. I am trying to retrieve all rows having same role with their respective ids in a new excel file. I tried below code to achieve that -

```
import pandas

file1 = file1.xlsx
file2 = file2.xlsx
data1 = pandas.read_excel(file1)
data2 = pandas.read_excel(file2)
dataDiff = data1[data1 != data2]
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('result.xlsx')
dataDiff.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',index=false)
writer.save()
```

But this block of is giving me below error

```
Exception: Can only compare identically-labeled Dataframe objects'
```

I am still a newbie in python. Any help would be appreciated. Can we use anything other than pandas?

Comment: You might want to start with `m = data1.merge(data2, on='role')` and see if that gets you towards what you want?

Comment: please check my answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask=data1.role.isin(data2.role.tolist())
data_equal=data1[mask]
```

---

```
data_diff=data1[~mask]
```

---

We can also use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) as suggested **@Jon Clements**:

```
data_equal=data.merge(data2,on='role',how='inner')
```

or

```
data_diff= ( data1.merge(data2,on='role',how='outer',indicator=True)     
                  .query('_merge == "left_only"')
                  .drop('_merge',axis=1) )
```